# Express / Node Error no extension was provided

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

I ran into a problem with Nodejs, when navigation to my localhost:3000/surveys I receive an error message. I followed an extensive tutorial and I could not identify the cause of the error despite searching for answers via stackoverflow, according to the tutorial everything should work fine. When I navigate to localhost:3000/users it works perfectly fine. My route file users.js responds with a resource as desired, I just can't get the localhost:3000/surveys to work. Below I posted the error code and the controller, route and model of my survey.

Error I receive

```
Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.

   at new View (/Users/testuser/WebstormProjects/test/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:62:11)
   at EventEmitter.render (/Users/testuser/WebstormProjects/test/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:569:12)
   at ServerResponse.render (/Users/testuser/WebstormProjects/test/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:961:7)
   at /Users/testuser/WebstormProjects/test/app.js:60:7
   at Layer.handle_error (/Users/testuser/WebstormProjects/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
   at trim_prefix (/Users/testuser/WebstormProjects/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:310:13)
   at /Users/testuser/WebstormProjects/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
   at Function.process_params (/Users/testuser/WebstormProjects/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
   at next (/Users/testuser/WebstormProjects/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
   at Layer.handle_error (/Users/testuser/WebstormProjects/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:73:5)
   at trim_prefix (/Users/testuser/WebstormProjects/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:310:13)
   at /Users/testuser/WebstormProjects/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
   at Function.process_params (/Users/testuser/WebstormProjects/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
   at next (/Users/testuser/WebstormProjects/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
   at /Users/testuser/WebstormProjects/test/app.js:39:3
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/testuser/WebstormProjects/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

Model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var SurveySchema = new Schema ({
created: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
    von: Date,
    bis: Date,
    kmStart: Number,
    kmEnde: Number,
    strecke: String,
    zweck: String,
    privat: Boolean,
    fahrer: String,
    fahrzeug: String
});

SurveySchema.statics = {
load: function(id, cb){
    this.findOne({_id : id}).exec(cb);
    }
};

mongoose.model('Survey', SurveySchema);
```

Controller

```
require('../models/survey');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Survey = mongoose.model("Survey");

exports.post = function(req, res){
var survey = new Survey(req.body);
survey.save();
res.jsonp(survey);
}
```

Routes

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var surveys = require('../controllers/surveysController');

/* POST /surveys */
router.post('/', surveys.post);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: It looks like your actual call to `render()` is in app.js, but you haven't set up a view engine (so Express knows how to load and format the response).

Answer (score 1):

@all I just wanted to say I did fix the problem. I think it was because I used the wrong MongoDB in the app.js file. The change solved the problem.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydb');
```

To

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your app.js? Let's make sure you told the app to use the router for /surveys

Comment: @Gonen, questions should be asked in the comments of a question, not the answers area.

Answer (score 0):

This is the app.js as requested

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var users = require('./routes/users');
var surveys = require('./routes/surveys');

var app = express();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydb');
var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', function callback(){
  console.log("connection to MongoDB failed");
});

db.once('open', function callback(){
  console.log("connection to MongoDB success");
});

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/surveys', surveys);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
    if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I may know the problem, but I'll adjust my answer if it doesn't work. 
In your code, I don't see anywhere that a templating engine is set. You can do this by installing something like Jade or Swig.

`npm install jade --save`

Then telling express that it's there.

`app.set('view engine', 'jade');`

Then you can set your variables that will be rendered in your template.

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message, //message will be rendered
    error: {} 
  });
});
```

Then the template; with Jade, it preprocesses the code to actual html. So, the message will render to `<h1>This is an error message</h1>`

```
html
  head
  body
    h1= message
```

Of course you can write out the HTML; this is just for convenience. Here is a link to [Jade](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) or [Swig](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/). If you use Swig, which I do, you can render your data in the pages with two opening and closing curly braces. For example,

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
  Error: {{message}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I should have mentioned I removed Jade from the app.js file and package.json dependencies to not have it rendered in HTML and host an API, I apologize- still a n00b in this area. I use the RESTClient plugin for Firefox with a Content-Type application/json header to test the http://localhost:3000/surveys.